# How do I get the RequestDispatcher to forward to the desired jsp which is in a seperate folder?

Tags: jsp, servlets, requestdispatcher

I am trying to use requestdispatcher to forward to a jsp inside another folder. None of them are in the WEB-INF folder. The problem is that it will show it redirected as the tab will show the title of the desired page but the url shows that of the servlet and the page is blank.
File system is (all under Web Pages not WEB-INF):

current jsp: Web Pages/index/index.jsp
desired jsp: Web Pages/admin/monster-html/admin.jsp

[image: picture of problem]

I tried:

This got me to that page displayed

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/admin/monster-html/admin.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

this got me to an error page

```
RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("//admin/monster-html/admin.jsp");
requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

this too got me to an error page

```
response.sendRedirect("//admin/monster-html/admin.jsp");return;
```

this got me to a 404 error page

```
response.sendRedirect("/admin/monster-html/admin.jsp");return;
```

Ialso tried jsp mapping

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>admin</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/admin/monster-html/admin.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>admin</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/admin</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

here is what I have currently

```
request.setAttribute("projects", projects);
request.setAttribute("sme_pending", sme_pending);
request.setAttribute("complaints", complaints);
request.setAttribute("freelancers_pending", freelancers_pending);

RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/admin/monster-html/admin.jsp");
requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

I want to call the admin.jsp and use the request too.

EDIT:

[image: picture of problem]

Comment: Please share screenshot of your file structure.

Comment: @ErShakirAnsari I added the file system

Comment: The fact that you're still seeing the url of the servlet is perfectly normal and expected: you're doing a forward, not a redirect. That all happens at server-side. The browser doesn't know and care about it: it asked to go to /login, so it goes to /login. The fact that you see the title of the JSP in the browser title shows that the forward did happen. Look at the source code of your JSP and at the logs to see why the page doesn't display anything.

Comment: @JBNizet the logs don't show an error or exception... which is making it hard to debug. I removed any code that uses values from the request and still nothing. I ran the JSP on its own and it ran properly